# What does "the scaffolding of biology" mean here?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience

In Zoltan Torey's The Conscious Mind, the author discusses the emerge of self-awareness:

> Turning to the changes that the acquisition of language instantiated, Damasio reflects on these changes in some detail:
>
> To hold extensive memory records not only of motor-skills but also of the facts and events, in particular of personal facts and events, those that make up **the scaffolding of biology, of personhood and the individual’s identity**, these depending on the ability to reconstruct and manipulate memory records in a working brain-space, parallel to the perceptual space, an off-line holding area where time can be suspended during a delay and decisions freed from the tyranny of immediate responses.

What does this mean?

Comment: It's just a metaphor. Look up scaffolding in a dictionary.

Comment: This sort of question actually has nothing to do with biology, and would be more appropriate on SE English Language Learners. However, in addition to it being pretentious twaddle, I don’t find it a very good metaphor, given that scaffolding only supports something (and not necessarily even that) until it is built or repaired. “Framework” strikes me as better. But, again we are in a realm other than biology — perhaps philosophy.

Comment: I agree with David that the specific meaning here is not really worth dissecting or understanding from the perspective of biology; it won't bring you any closer to any knowledge or understanding of biology.